# How can I find all immediate sub-directories of the current directory on Linux?

Tags: linux

How can I find all immediate sub-directories of the current directory on Linux?

Comment: Immediate as in the level of directories within the current directory or the entire underlying structure below it?

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way is to exploit the shell globbing capabilities by writing `echo */`.

If you like to use `ls`, e.g. to apply formatting/sorting options, make it `ls -d */`.

Explanation:

- The slash ensures that only directories are considered, not files.
- Option `-d`: list directories themselves, not their contents

Answer (score 15):

If you just need to get a list of sub directories (without caring about the language/tool to use) `find` is the command that you need.

It's able to find anything in a directory tree.

If by *immediate* you mean that you need only the child directories, but not the grandchild `-maxdepth` option will do the trick. Then `-type` will let you specify that you are only looking for directories:

```
find YOUR_DIRECTORY -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
```

Comment: This solution is not correct: The result includes the parent directory `YOUR_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: @oberlies: OP didn't specify that he only wanted the name of the directories without the relative path. For many (most?) purposes `./dir` and `dir` are exactly the same.

Comment: The proposed command results in the following list: `YOUR_DIRECTORY YOUR_DIRECTORY/subdir01 YOUR_DIRECTORY/subdir02 YOUR_DIRECTORY/...`, so the first list entry not correct.

Comment: @oberlies: uh, sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. Yes, you're right. Adding `-mindepth 1` would do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below -

```
$ ls -l | grep '^d'
```

Brief explanation: As in long listing, the directories start with 'd', so the above command (`grep`) filters out those result, that start with 'd', which are nothing but directories.

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I was using `find . -type d` and it was matching the current directory and I *only* wanted subdirectories, and `find ./* -type d` worked great.

Although it looks like that also finds sub-sub-dirs etc, which wasn't an issue for my situation. There's probably another flag for that.

Comment: Your answer helped me, adding the **-maxdepth 1** option played the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

ls | grep /$

the grep find anything ending in / which directories do.

Comment: This is not a general solution. It assumes that `ls` is aliased to `ls -F`.