# Iterate shell script over list of subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, loops, ls

I have a folder (let's call it `folder1` that contains only subdirectories. I want to write a shell script that iterates several python scripts over each subdirectory. As it is, I have to type out the absolute path to each subdirectory within the script, but I want to be able to `cd` to `folder1` and simply run the shell script from there and have it automatically iterate over the subdirectories, whatever their name or the location of `folder1`.

Current code (saved as shellscript.sh):

```
#! /bin/sh

declare -a arr=("/path/folder1/subdir1"  "/path/folder1/subdir2" "/path/folder1/subdir3" "/path/folder1/subdir4")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    python /path/to/pythonscript1.py "$i"
    python /path/to/pythonscript2.py "$i"
done
```

Then I can run it by opening up a Terminal (Mac OSX v 10.13.6) and run `sh path/to/shellscript.sh`. I want the `arr` declaration early in the script to automatically populate based on the contents of whatever cwd I'm in. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747905/how-can-i-find-all-immediate-sub-directories-of-the-current-directory-on-linux) useful link and was able to run that as a standalone command in the Terminal but can't figure out how to incorporate it into the shell script. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for dir in ./* ./**/*    # list directories in the current directory
    do
        python $dir
    done
```

./* are files in dir and ./**/* are files in subfolders.

Make sure you have only python files in your directory it will run all the files in that directory