# Iterate through files in sub-folders inside a main folder in bash

Tags: linux, bash

The question is really simple, I know how to do it in Python but I want to do it in Linux shell (bash).

I have a main folder `Dataset` inside which there are multiple sub-folders `Dataset_FinalFolder_0_10` all the way up to `Dataset_FinalFolder_1090_1100` each with 10 files.

I want to run a program on each of those files. In Python I would do this with something like:

```
for folder in /path/to/folders:
    for file in folder:
        run program
```

Is there any way so mimic this in Shell / bash?

I have this code which I have used for more direct iterations:

```
for i in /path/to/folder/*; 
do program "$i"; 
done
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nicely asked, but this has been asked and answered many times here.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that there are no files mixed in with the folders, and no folders mixed in with the files:

```
for folder in /path/to/Dataset/*; do
    for file in "$folder"/*; do
        program "$file"
    done
done
```

Alternatively, it is possible to give more than one `*`:

```
for file in /path/to/Dataset/*/*; do
    program "$file"
done
```

If you aren't sure about the folder contents, then `find` can help. This example selects files in just the first-level subdirectories of the given folder and xargs calls program for each one:

```
find /path/to/Dataset/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f |\
xargs -n1 program
```

The find method may also be useful if `.../*/*/*/...` could expand to a huge number of paths. On linux, the commandline length limit is shown by:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

On my machine that is 2^21 (~2 million) characters. So the limit is high, but worth keeping at the back of your mind that there is one.

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux perspective, you have to watch out for properly escaping spaces, new lines, etc which can get kinda funky.  There are multiple references for why not to do it - see

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

And

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead

That said...

You can always use the `find` command wiht the `-exec` option -

```
find /path/to/top/level -type f -exec /path/to/processing/program {} \;
```

The `\;` at the end is required to indicate the end of the exec

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops in either Python or the shell unless you have so many files that you are running up against "argument list too long" errors.

```
for file in /path/to/folders/*/*; do
    program "$file"
done
```

This is equivalent to the Python code

```
from glob import glob
from subprocess import run

for file in glob('/path/to/folders/*/*'):
    run(['program', file])
```

Of course, if `program` is at all competently written, you can probably simply do

```
program /path/to/folders/*/*
```

This corresponds to

```
run(['program'] + glob('/path/to/folders/*/*')
```

If `program` accepts a list of file name arguments, but you do need to break up the command line to avoid "argument list too long" errors, try

```
printf '%s\0' /path/to/folders/*/* |
xargs -r0 program
```

(The zero-terminator pattern is a GNU `find` extension, as is the `-r` option.)

Answer (score -2):

```
for dir in ./* ./**/*    # list directories in the current directory
do
    python $dir
done
```

./* are files in dir and ./**/* are files in subfolders.

Make sure you have only python files in your directory it will run all the files in that directory

Actually I have already answered it here
[Iterate shell script over list of subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909302/iterate-shell-script-over-list-of-subdirectories/54909588#54909588)